# i need to create a fallback action in rasa chatbot?

Tags: action, chatbot, multilingual, rasa, rasa-nlu

I created a action which has two buttons. And If i type instead of selecting buttons and it is not related to the button(intent) or the text which is related to other action. I want to show that previous action with buttons.

```
class ActionPayrollandattMenu(Action):
    def name(self) -> Text:
        return "action_AB"

    def run(self, dispatcher: CollectingDispatcher,
            tracker: Tracker,
            domain: Dict[Text, Any]) -> List[Dict[Text, Any]]:

        message = "Please select your preferred option:"
        buttons = [
            {"title": "AAA", "id": "A"},
            {"title": "BBB", "id": "B"},
        ]
        #print("Tracker.Event",tracker.events,"\n\n")      
        language = tracker.slots.get("language")
        intent_name = tracker.latest_message.get("intent").get("name")
        print("A intent name: ",intent_name)
        latest_action = tracker.latest_action_name
        print("A latest action: ",latest_action)
        #print(f"language: {language}")  
        if language and language != "en":
            translator = Translator()
            message = translator.translate("Please select  your preferred option:", dest=language).text
        else:
            message = "Please select your preferred option:"
        buttons = [
            {"title": "AAA", "id": "A"},
            {"title": "BBB", "id": "B"}
        ]
        for button in buttons:
            if language and language != "en":
                button["title"] = translator.translate(button["title"], dest=language).text
        dispatcher.utter_message(text=message, buttons=buttons)

        IST = pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata')
        date = (datetime.datetime.now(IST) + datetime.timedelta(minutes=2)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        entities = tracker.latest_message.get("entities") 
        date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        reminder=remind(date,entities)

        return [reminder]
    

class ActionFallback(Action):
    def name(self) -> Text:
        return "action_fallback"

    def run(self, dispatcher: CollectingDispatcher,
            tracker: Tracker,
            domain: Dict[Text, Any]) -> List[Dict[Text, Any]]:

        intent_name = tracker.latest_message.get("intent").get("name")
        if intent_name not in ["A", "B"]:
            if "A" in tracker.latest_message.get("text").lower():
                return [FollowupAction("action_A")]
            elif "B" in tracker.latest_message.get("text").lower():
                return [FollowupAction("action_B")]
            else:
                dispatcher.utter_message("Sorry, I didn't understand. Please select your preferred option:")
                return [FollowupAction("action_AB")]
        return []
```

How can i create a fall back action for that?